# how to set up a gui on ec2 ubuntu 14.04 and connect to it from my local ubuntu computer using Remmina

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I'm having trouble connecting to my ec2 via Remmina.  I went through the process of installing ubuntu-desktop and vncserver on my ec2 instance.

I can ssh into the ec2, and start up vncserver.

I made security rule in my amazon dashboard and opened up a port 5901

But when I open Remmina on my local ubuntu machine, I'm lost.

Some people are talking about connecting through a port 5901?  Why?

I'm failing to see the difference between ssh-ing into my ec2 versus using remmina.

Edit:

was able to get this to work with the following params:

**protocol:**  VNCS-Virtual network computing

**server:** use your IPv4 Public IP with port 5901 after (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5901)

leave everything else blank and just click "Connect"... you should be prompted for your password and that's it!  good luck.  I tried it without the :5901 at the end, but it didn't work, so I'm not totally sure what gives on that.

Answer (score 0):

The '5901' is the port that the service (on the server) is listening on, and as you found, you need to tell the client which port to use.

The rule that you added to the EC2 instance's security group was also a critical step.

By omitting the port when connecting from client to server, a lot of applications will use their default port.

SSH vs Remmina:
These are two different protocols, managed by different services, running on different ports. So being able to connect via SSH to a remote node doesn't mean you should be able to remote desktop / VNC / Remmina to the same host.
It does, however, help to troubleshoot, because you have a view on both sides of the connection (client and server).